# Recording system sound using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I have question about recording system sound (not microphone, whole system sound - everything that goes to the speakers from PC). I know that normally I should use WASAPI or BASS, yet WASAPI has such horrible documentation (at least for me), that I just don't know what they actually want me to do to make this work. BASS documentation is not so appealing too, compared to excellent Qt samples.

Is there any Qt wrapper or something similar that will allow me to capture this endpoint audio in simple way without using WASAPI directly?

Comment: Qt on windows is still hopelessly stuck on MME.

Comment: So is there any way to do this SIMPLE way without analysing these horrible samples M$ provided? Qt does it simple way - giving only part of code that does ONE particular thing with short commentary why is looks like that. Most of the times it's self explanatory anyway. Meanwhile M$ gave a sample that does several things at once and leaves you alone with something like "month or two and you will guess what is what in there and why it looks like that".

Comment: Well, it should still work with MME. Thing is stereo mix recording is by default disabled in windows. So go to your recording devices setup in control panel, right click in the empty space below your mic and line and select "show disabled devices" and then enable it. Afterwards, it should be visible to Qt.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible that program will enable it automatically? I mean - I want it to be rather portable and requiring minimal intervention from user. Enabling this device is not as bad as installing 3rd party audio driver which emulates microphone while being endpoint audio recorder, I mean this -> http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm .
Yet it's still not "I click and it works! Yay!". Actually I ordered it to show disabled devices and I still don't see anything new there.

Comment: Not from Qt. It just uses what the system provides. It might be possible from the M$ APIs - I don't know, I avoid using their stuff as much as possible.

Comment: If everything from them is documented like WASAPI then I really find it hard to be suprised. Should I see this mix recording device in sound manager?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, after you show the hidden devices and enable the "stereo mix" recording device from the sound settings in control panel, the device will be readily available for use in Qt.

[image]

You can quickly query the system to verify that:

```
auto info = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);
foreach (auto i, info) qDebug() << i.deviceName();
```

Which for me outputs:

```
"Microphone (Realtek High Defini"
"Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini"
```

From then on, you can follow the Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html) and [tutorials](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html).

Comment: Yet I see no new devices there, is it normal?

Comment: There is actually nothing to enable after I ordered to show hidden. Nothing new there.

Comment: In that case your device drivers might not support it.

Comment: And that's a problem - what if not only my driver does not support it?

Comment: It is not a frequently used feature. Get a signal splitter, an extra cable, plug splitter into line out, put one end in your speakers, the other end into line in and you are set. BTW I have a 1000$ professional USB audio interface here as well, it doesn't support stereo out recording either.

Comment: Also, keep in mind there might be a way to achieve that with the MS APIs, but I'd rather go get the cable than deal with that...