# How to record from audio mixer "what-you-hear" in Windows. ( Using Qt )

Tags: c++, windows, qt, audio, webrtc

I'm trying to figure how to record from audio mixer a.k.a. "what-you-hear" on Windows in order of recording audio that's being played in a video and also audio from microphone at same time. Are there a way to directly access to this as an especial kind of device or something like that? How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335454/recording-system-sound-using-qt

Comment: @ddriver Problem is mixer doesn't appears in all Windows systems, for example it didn't appears on mine :(

Comment: It is usually only hidden, but if you can't enable it, maybe your device / driver doesn't support it. For me it works for the integrated realtec device, but it is not available on my professional audio interface.

Comment: Uhm, was hidden and this works; but problem is I haven't a way to programatically enabling this device or ask for enabling it or so. Do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: There is no way to do it from Qt, it might be possible to do from the MS APIs, but I wouldn't know it.